# Interpolating ground water depths

Tags: qgis, raster, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate the depths of ground water aquifers with a few known data points from the field study. The objective here is to map the contours of that particular catchment's depth of bedrock or aquifers so that we can strongly assume the ground water depth values for the ones we don't have a depth value?
 Our study area is on the peri urban small towns of Bangalore, India

Comment: Please make sure there is a question. I only see the objective explained with a question mark after it.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

Have u tried the interpolation plugin already? its fairly easy to use.
https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_interpolation.html